# Why do I get this error when reading this url with rebol

Tags: rebol

http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=759

```
>> read http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&s
eqNum=759
connecting to: www.informit.com
** User Error: HTTP forwarding error: Scheme https for URL htt
ps://memberservices.informit.com/checkLogin.ashx?partner=53&r=
http%3a%2f%...
** Near: read http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=do
tnet&seqNum=759
>>
```

This doesn't happen with Firefox, is it possible to "simulate" firefox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL is being forwarded to an HTTPS page. Rebol/Core and Rebol/View do not support the HTTPS protocol.

Answer (score 0):

An update.  REBOL release 2.7.8 includes many goodies.  Secure HTTP included.  Forward to and from HTTPS.  Many other previously premium utilities now included in the proprietary distribution.

As of December 12, 2012, the release date of open source REBOL/3, things have changed.

http://www.rebol.com/article/0519.html

[fanboy]
But even with REBOL/3 open, REBOL 2.7.8 is a very powerful, polished and productive development system.  Free to use.  Worthy of inclusion in all personal and office toolkits.
[/fanboy]